# How would I show that $\sin$ is continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I've been asked to show that $\sin x$ is a continuous function using the epsilon-delta definition of continuity. I am completely stumped, I've tried using identities and I can't think of anything. I am trying to show that $|\sin(x) - \sin(y)|$ goes to $0$ as $|x - y|$ goes to $0$. However I don't know any identities specific to the sum of two sines and all the other ones I know I tried at random and they don't seem to help. Could someone point me in the right direction (a hint as opposed to an answer)?

Comment: How do you define $\sin x$? - Nevertheless, using $\sin x-\sin y = 2\cos\frac{x+y}2\sin\frac{x-y}2$ you should be able to carry on

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hint:

$$\sin(x) - \sin (y) = 2\cos \left(\frac{x+y}{2} \right) \sin \left( \frac{x-y}{2}\right)$$

$$|\sin(x)| \leq |x|$$

Comment: Yes,those are indeed the relevant identities to use. The OP has basically the right idea,but he/she needed the correct identities. The proof isn't difficult, but you have to begin it correctly and that's not obvious.

Comment: Thank you! That's the identity I needed.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, here's a full standard proof. This proof actually proves *uniform continuity* of sin(x) on $\mathbb R$, which of course, implies continuity on the entire real line.

So assume $$|\sin(x)| \leq |x|$$ and consider the identity

$$\sin(x) - \sin (y) = 2\cos \left(\frac{x+y}{2} \right) \sin \left( \frac{x-y}{2}\right)$$

Let $\epsilon>0$ and $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$. We want
$$\left|f(x)-f(y)\right|<\epsilon\implies \left|\sin x-\sin y\right|<\epsilon\implies \left|2\cos\frac{x+y}2\sin\frac{x-y}2\right|$$
Because 
$$\left|2\cos\frac{x+y}2\sin\frac{x-y}2\right|\le 2\left|\sin\frac{x-y}2\right|$$
it suffices
$$2\left|\sin\frac{x-y}2\right|<\epsilon$$
when
$$\left|x-y\right|<\delta\implies \left|\frac{x-y}2\right|<\delta$$
SInce $\left|\sin x\right|\le \left|x\right|$,
$$2\left|\sin\frac{x-y}2\right|\le 2\left|\frac{x-y}2\right|<2\delta$$

Choose $\delta=\frac{\epsilon}{2}>0$ Notice $\delta$ doesn't depend on $x,y$, Therefore,the continuity is uniform and that does it! Q.E.D.

(Yeah,I'm old school with the Q.E.D., sue me.........LOL)

In my original answer, I thought Alexander Bogomolny had come up with an extremely clever proof. It uses a fairly simple geometric construction using high school trigonometry and the fact sin (x) is an odd function and it doesn't require the "double angle difference" identity used in the direct proof hinted at by Hagen above.

Unfortunately, the trade-off is that it's pretty lengthy and if you're not good at geometry, the construction might evade you. However, as I said, it is rather clever and doesn't require any complicated identities like that standard proof does. The proof can be found [here](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/do_you_know/CosineIsContinuous.shtml).

However, Paramanand Singh brought to my attention that it's beginning assumption-that t---->0 as y --->0 has not been proved. I'm not sure if this is a deal breaker if this assumption can be proved. To be honest,if it can be-the resulting proof will be so lengthy I'm not sure it's worth the effort anymore!

Comment: The proof in your link is circular. It clearly mentions that it assumes as $t\to 0$ the variable $y\to 0$. This is what needs to be proved and is based on the inequality $\sin t<t$ for $0<t<\pi/2$. I am amazed at the ingenuity with which people discover circular proofs. Also I find it disturbing that the proof is mentioned in cut-the-knot which has been one of my favorite websites since college days.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Ok,I'm really upset if that's true and I didn't notice it.But does that make the proof circular if one of it's assumptions isn't proved? INCOMPLETE, yes-not circular.It WAS late and I was tired,but Bogomolny is usually a very reliable source for such matters and I took it on faith.Clearly something NONE of us as mathematicians should EVER do. I'll check it over carefully and see if it can be repaired. Meanwhile,you should email Bogomolny and let him know since you found the error.

Comment: Uh-did someone deduct a point for kicks again? Just curious.

Comment: Btw I did not deduct a point. I am explicit about my downvote and hate anonymous downvoting.

Comment: Usually I trust the website cut-the-knot, but I got curious when I saw that the limit of $\sin t$ as $t\to 0$ was somehow made equivalent to an algebraic limit $\lim_{y\to 0}y/\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}$. The behavior of transcendentals usually transcends algebra and it is precisely the non-algebraic parts of calculus which make it interesting. That's how I became skeptical.